# Ionic 2 ion-selected doesn't show the selected option

Tags: select, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using model driven form to select default option, so `residence` is already set:

```
<ion-select formControlName="residence">
   <ion-option [value]='"0"'>{{freeCalcForm.controls.partyAName.value}}</ion-option>
   <ion-option [value]='"1"'>{{freeCalcForm.controls.partyBName.value}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

I don't see the selected value:
[image]

But clicking on the ion-select shows that the value **is already selected correctly:**

[image]

I tried `selected="true"` and `selected="selected"` on first option without any effect.

Comment: I the beginning it was working but then I get the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind a model to your select:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="myModel">
```

and set your default selection in the model. For example:

```
// page.html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
  <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
</ion-select>

// page.js
export class BasicPage {
  gender: string = "f";
}
```

Example truncated from [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/selects/basic).

Comment: I'm using model driven forms, residence is set and shows correct selected option in the dropdown.